# Retrieve PDF file generated on the fly and embedded in a HTML page

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve a PDF file embedded in a HTML page using Python 2.7. I have tried using urllib and BeautifulSoup, but with no success. My problem is that I can't find any PDF link when I display the source code of the page.

Here is an example of the PDF I am trying to download : [link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=FR&language=fr&productNumber=T1503&brand=SIGMA&PageToGoToURL=%2Fsafety-center.html).

How can I download this file on my computer using Python ?

EDIT : I just realized that the PDF is probably generated on the fly. Is it even possible to automatically download this type of file ?

Comment: I've to do the same thing. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @haltman No. I tried a few more things but nothing worked. I gave up, but I am still interested in the solution if you ever find it!

Comment: I got my solution, its a little raw but work well, I use selenium library to automatically open the web page and pyautogui to interact with dialog windows to save the file, tell me if you need a working example

Comment: @haltman Sure a working example would be great! You can post it as an answer here, and if I can make it work I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,

thats my working solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('your-link')  # Load page
browser.find_element_by_id('download').click()  # here I press the download button of the PDF   
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
browser.close()
```